# es5BrowserSupport by Angular

Tags: npm-install, npm-update, angular-cli-v9

I have updated my Angular CLI, with version 10.0.5 (globally and locally both) And while I am trying to build my angular project by below command-

```
ng build
```

I am getting below error-

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:  Data path ""
> should NOT have additional properties(es5BrowserSupport).

While I explored this error I found that-

@angular/cli required minimum version 7.3  &
@angular-devkit/build-angular required minimum version 0.13

But I think I have the updated versions because I re-checked and it was showing I already have the updated versions of both the packages.

FYI..I can't comment this option (es5BrowserSupport : true) in Angular.json, I want to keep this because if I comment this option it's giving other issues.

Now I am not understanding what I am doing wrong here. Can anyone suggest some way to resolve this? Because currently I am unable to run my project because of this issue.

FYI, my old Angular CLI version was-

```
@angular/cli": "^8.3.20"
```

Answer (score 11):

The property `es5BrowserSupport` was deprecated and has been removed.

The inclusion for ES5 polyfills will be determined from the browsers listed in the browserslist configuration.

> **BREAKING CHANGE** 
> Deprecated browser builder option es5BrowserSupport has been removed. The inclusion for ES5 polyfills will be determined from the browsers listed in the browserslist configuration.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/17484